# Renaming the Option, Some, and None sealed types to a domain-specific language?

Tags: scala

I'd like to declare some types *that are* `Option`, `Some`, and `None` but are referred to by *different names* that are more apropos to my domain in order to improve code readability. Because although the functionality of `Option` does map 1:1 to my problem domain, it's not exactly obvious at first glance so calling this type "Option" would be confusing.

My first thought was to use type aliases:

```
type Foo[T] = Option[T]
type Bar[T] = Some[T]
type Bash = None.type
```

However, I can't use this new "language" when pattern matching:

```
def example(f: Foo[Int]) = f match {
  case Bar(_) => "got bar"
  case Bash => "got bash"
}
/*
On line 2: error: not found: value Bar
         case Bash => "got bash"
              ^
On line 3: error: not found: value Bash
       Identifiers that begin with uppercase are not pattern variables but match the value in scope.
*/
```

Next I thought to simply subclass, but `Option` is sealed – for good reason – so that's out of the picture:

```
trait Foo[T] extends Option[T]
// error: illegal inheritance from sealed class Option
```

Last of all I thought I was clever in trying to *rename on import*:

```
// BEGIN Foo.scala
import scala.{Option => Foo}
import scala.{Some => Bar}
import scala.{None => Bash}

// This works!
def example(f: Foo[Int]) = f match {
  case Bar(_) => "got bar"
  case Bash => "got bash"
}
```

... but there is no way to *export* the newly declared names for use outside of the current file :

```
// BEGIN OtherFileThatUsesFoo.scala

// Doesn't compile because Option must be called either "Option" or "Foo" and not both
case class Person(child: Option[Person], foo: Foo[Int])
```

Is there another option I'm missing, besides simply implementing `Option` with a different name?

Comment: You do the type alias but also alias the companion objects like `val Foo = Option` that should work - however, I would question the readability, all **Scala** developers know what `Option` is, seeing a new name / type may be confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez has it in the comments!

```
type Foo[T] = Option[T]
val Foo = Option
type Bar[T] = Some[T]
val Bar = Some
type Bash = None.type
val Bash = None

// Compiles and runs correctly!
def example(f: Foo[Int]) = f match {
  case Bar(_) => "got bar"
  case Bash => "got bash"
}
```

I needed to "alias" the companion objects as well, a la `val Foo = Option`.